# How to group by without duplication - Apache Pig

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-pig

I need to find the order value (unit price multiplied by quantity of products).  However, my results show duplication of order_id. How can i remove the duplication such that i get the order_id followed by order value? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Code:

```
orderdetails = load '/user/bigdata/order_detail.tbl' using PigStorage('|') as

(ORDER_ID:int,PRODUCT_ID:int,CUSTOMER_ID:int,SALESPERSON_ID:int,UNIT_PRICE:float,QUANTITY:int,DISCOUNT:float);

ordervalue = FOREACH orderdetails GENERATE ORDER_ID, UNIT_PRICE*QUANTITY as VALUE;

order_filter = FILTER ordervalue BY (ORDER_ID > 10269) AND (ORDER_ID < 10280);

groupOrder = GROUP order_filter BY (ORDER_ID);

groupOrdersum = FOREACH groupOrder GENERATE (order_filter.ORDER_ID),SUM(order_filter.VALUE) as ORDERVALUE;

dump groupOrdersum;
```

Results

```
({(10270),(10270)},1376.0) ({(10271)},48.0) ({(10272),(10272),(10272)},1455.9999694824219) ({(10273),(10273),(10273),(10273),(10273)},2142.399932861328) ({(10274),(10274)},538.5999908447266) ({(10275),(10275)},307.1999969482422) ({(10276),(10276)},420.0) ({(10277),(10277)},1200.8000183105469) ({(10278),(10278),(10278),(10278)},1488.7999877929688) ({(10279)},468.0)
```

Comment: Please use the code formatter to make this post more readable.

Comment: Can u share smaller input and corresponding output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the:

```
groupOrdersum = FOREACH groupOrder GENERATE (order_filter.ORDER_ID),SUM(order_filter.VALUE) as ORDERVALUE;
```

to

```
groupOrdersum = FOREACH groupOrder GENERATE 
    group AS ORDERID,
    SUM(order_filter.VALUE) as ORDERVALUE;
```

I think right now you're generating the grouped bag of order ids (i.e the value) and not the actual key.